# "an error occurred while collecting items to be installed" on eclipse "check for updates"

Tags: eclipse, updates

I'm trying to update Eclipse plugins (using "Check for Updates") but I keep getting a long list of errors. I assume it is something wrong with the list of update sites but I've been able to update before. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

(Goes on like this for many lines...)

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,ch.qos.logback.slf4j,1.0.7.v20121108-1250
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.google.appengine.eclipse.core,3.2.4.v201306061638-rel-r42
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.google.appengine.eclipse.datatools,3.2.4.v201306061638-rel-r42
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.google.appengine.eclipse.webtools,3.2.4.v201306061638-rel-r42
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.google.appengine.eclipse.webtools.e42,3.2.4.v201306061638-rel-r42
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.rpc,3.2.4.v201306061638-rel-r42
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm,3.2.4.v201306061638-rel-r42
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm_backend,3.2.4.v201306061638-rel-r42
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.google.gdt.eclipse.appsmarketplace,3.2.4.v201306061638-rel-r42
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.google.gdt.eclipse.core,3.2.4.v201306061638-rel-r42
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.google.gdt.eclipse.gph,3.2.4.v201306061638-rel-r42
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.google.gdt.eclipse.gph.e36,3.2.4.v201306061638-rel-r42
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.google.gdt.eclipse.gph.hge,3.2.4.v201306061638-rel-r42
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.google.gdt.eclipse.gph.subclipse,3.2.4.v201306061638-rel-r42
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.google.gdt.eclipse.gph.subversive,3.2.4.v201306061638-rel-r42
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.google.gdt.eclipse.login,3.2.4.v201306061638-rel-r42
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.google.gdt.eclipse.managedapis,3.2.4.v201306061638-rel-r42
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.google.gdt.eclipse.maven,3.2.4.v201306061638-rel-r42
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.google.gdt.eclipse.maven.e37,3.2.4.v201306061638-rel-r42
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.google.gdt.eclipse.platform,3.2.4.v201306061638-rel-r42
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.google.gdt.eclipse.platform.e42,3.2.4.v201306061638-rel-r42
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.google.gdt.eclipse.platform.shared,3.2.4.v201306061638-rel-r42
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite,3.2.4.v201306061638-rel-r42
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.ext,3.2.4.v201306061638-rel-r42
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.google.gwt.eclipse.core,3.2.4.v201306061638-rel-r42
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.google.gwt.eclipse.oophm,3.2.4.v201306061638-rel-r42
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got this error when trying to install the gae plugin for eclipse. My solution was to remove the update site and then re-add and try install again.

Comment: It is dumb that this solves the problem, but apparently something gets corrupted with the URL and it just won't work until you delete it and add it again.

Answer (score 1):

After spending a few hours, I realized I was on VPN.  When I disabled it, the error went away!